# magento paginate a custom collection

Tags: magento

I have a custom page where I have displayed custom products using custom queries by crossing models against brands. I have an array of products Ids now what I can't seem to figure out is how to implement the magento's default paging system.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Controller (IndexController.php) file
In index controller simply load the layout and render it.

```
<?php
class Abc_Example_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Step 2: Layout (custom.xml) file
Put the under given code in the layout file of module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <example_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="example/collection" name="collection" template="example/collection.phtml" />
       </reference>
   </example_index_index>
</layout>
```

here is code for block where you can define collection

```
<?php
class Abc_Example_Block_Collection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('example/collection')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

you have to define custom collection which return the product id as per your requirement.in above code 
here is the phtml file where you can get pagination

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Custom Collection') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($collection->getSize()): ?>
<table id="my-custom-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('ID #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Title') ?></th>
            <th><span><?php echo $this->__('Created') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($collection as $_obj): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_obj->getCollectionId() ?></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $_obj->getTitle(); ?></span></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_obj->getCreatedTime()) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-custom-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('The collection is empty.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: hey I'm fairly new to magento and had no previous experience working on it but as asked by the client I have to do it any how so would you please care to explain where to use the code for collection creation, and I have an array of Ids, cant't I generate a collection from those products only ?

Comment: hi subhash,you can use 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>Your_productID_array);

Comment: hey the custom file is a .phtml view file so I dont have any classes there so please help me how to achieve this ?

Comment: so where you wrote your custom querys?? in view.phtml?

Comment: if you want pagination features you must create block for this

Comment: the page was done by someone else before me and he wrote that in page/3columns.phmtl file

Comment: Hi magExp

I am also experiencing the same problem. I have a collection which I have made after merging multiple arrays. This collection throws exception  “calling $collection->setCurPage() on a non-object in Pager.php”, which apparently shows that the collection object is null, which is not the case. I have seen its output using var_dump.

Where I am mistaken then ?

Comment: Yes I already tried this piece of code. I have a collection that is made by combining multiple arrays of different data. I don't know why pager is not working with this collection.

Comment: @shivam, could you please tell why my custom collection is not loaded in the page 2 of the pagination ...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229743/magento-custom-collection-not-loading-in-paginations-getnextpageurl